# Sales Ranking Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, ranking

I'm trying to work out the best way of ranking some products, based on both their overall sales to date, and the sales in the last x days (to show trends, hot products)

What I'd like to do is use both, so that the biggest sellers rank highly, but if they have sold out, they are moved down (no recent sales) or if they have particularly high recent sales they get jumped up.

With it being sales, the figures could be 10x different by product, so I'm assuming we need a logarithmic scale for this. What's the best way to combine the two?

Comment: "the sales in the last x days (to show trends, hot products)" You won;t get trends from "sales in the last x days" Trend is sustained (perhaps even increasing) rate of sale - the first derivative of the function not the integral (sum) over last period.

Comment: I guess the word trend is wrong, we're looking at a comparison between products, which have sold best compared to each other (rather than time) within the last X days

Comment: " which have sold best compared to each other" - best in terms of what? Quantity, revenue, profit? Anyway, my suggestion is to use a weighted average between: (1) average (per day) overall sales and (2) the average sales (per day) in the last 10 days, with a higher weight for the second.

Answer (score 3):

> What I'd like to do is use both, so that the biggest sellers rank highly, but if they have sold out, they are moved down (no recent sales) or if they have particularly high recent sales they get jumped up.

One particularly simple way of doing this would be to maintain, for each product, two [exponential moving averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average), one with a short factor, and one with a long factor. Note that each such average is simply updated by multiplying the average up to the day by some factor, and adding the number for that day multiplied by a complement factor.

You'll need to set the two factors based on your problem, but see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Time_Constant) an explanation on the relationship between this factor, and the effective time averaged.

The overall score for the product would be some total score taking into account both these averages.

> With it being sales, the figures could be 10x different by product, so I'm assuming we need a logarithmic scale for this. What's the best way to combine the two?

There is no best way - you'll need to try different options, and tune them until you're happy with the results.

If the long and short averages are *l* and *s*, then a general way of averaging (not the only one!) is *α f(l) + (1 - α) f(s)*, where *α* is some constant in *[0, 1]*, and *f* is a *damping function*. You've mentioned logarithms as a damping function, but you might find that, say, square root works better for your case (it also has less problems with small or zero arguments).

Comment: I'm not sure exponential decay is right here. To add more info, the 'products' we're selling for are tickets to events. We notice a U shaped buying trend - lots of sales at day 0, then this tails off and picks up again closer to the event day. All of those sales count though, they don't really become less relevent as time goes on.

We will always be comparing events on the same day, so they are all on a level playing field, so what matters is the overall number of sales they have made, with a weighting to recent sales just to prefer those that have some recent sales, over those that don't

Comment: @Ben Right, you can use exponential averages, sliding-window arithmetic averages, and just overall averages (which is what you just raised). There's no need for the short and long average to use the same scheme, even.

Comment: Thanks @Ami, anywhere I can see some real world examples to compare which might be more suitable?

Comment: @Ben Sure. I'd look around at econometrics and technical indicators for inspiration. The Wikipedia entries could be good starting points.